# How to scroll content outside of a tab in a selected tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How to scroll content outside of a tab in a selected tab?

I ran into a problem, in my application there is a profile page that separately uses '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs' in itself, each of the tabs displays the necessary content, how to use content scrolling in the selected tab, outside of this tab ***(as this is done in the instagram profile page)***

[image]

```
<Wrapper>
   <ProfileHeader /> // Userdata (avatar, username, buttons subscribe)
   <ProfileTabsNavigation /> // Content tabs (<ProfileWall />)
</Wrapper>

export const ProfileWall = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {POSTS.map(({ login, name, avatar, post, id, likes }) => (
        <ProfilePost
          key={id}
          userData={{ login, name, avatar, post, id, likes }}
        />
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

const Wrapper = styled.ScrollView`
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
`;
```

It turns out that now I can only scroll the  area, while the  remains in place, and there is a very small area for viewing content ...